# What does '*' { } construct means in Grails 3

Tags: grails

I generated a scaffold in Grails 3 and the update method have the following near the end;

```
'*' { respond domainname, [status: OK] }
```

What does the `'*' {}` construct means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffold differs what's being rendered for different request formats with

```
request.withFormat{
   ....
}
```

The star `'*'` describes that this action is happening for **all formats** (xml, json, html etc). 
Before that (at least for my code) code tells what's happening for `form`. And after that whats happening for all other formats.
And then the thing inside `{}` is pretty clear - it responds your object and passes a map where status value is OK. 
You can read more about withFormat in [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html)